# Starting storm nimbus command doesn't work

Tags: apache-storm

I have zookeeper servers, and I'm trying to install storm using those zk servers.

My storm.yaml file looks like:

```
storm.zookeeper.servers:
 - "ZKSERVER-0"
 - "ZKSERVER-1"
 - "ZKSERVER-2"
storm.local.dir: "/opt/apache-storm-2.2.0/data"
nimbus.host: "localhost"
supervisor.slots.ports:
 - 6700
 - 6701
 - 6702
 - 6703
```

I tested ping with those ZKSERVERs, and it worked fine.

However, when I start nimbus with `./storm nimbus` command, it doesn't show any error, but it doesn't end either.

```
root@69e55d266f5a:/opt/apache-storm-2.2.0/bin:> ./storm nimbus
Running: /usr/jdk64/jdk1.8.0_112/bin/java -server -Ddaemon.name=nimbus -Dstorm.options= -Dstorm.home=/opt/apache-storm-2.2.0 -Dstorm.log.dir=/opt/apache-storm-2.2.0/logs -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib:/opt/local/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/lib64 -Dstorm.conf.file= -cp /opt/apache-storm-2.2.0/*:/opt/apache-storm-2.2.0/lib/*:/opt/apache-storm-2.2.0/extlib/*:/opt/apache-storm-2.2.0/extlib-daemon/*:/opt/apache-storm-2.2.0/conf -Xmx1024m -Djava.deserialization.disabled=true -Dlogfile.name=nimbus.log -Dlog4j.configurationFile=/opt/apache-storm-2.2.0/log4j2/cluster.xml org.apache.storm.daemon.nimbus.Nimbus
```

The terminal just shows the above logs, and that doesn't change until I run `control+C`.

What could be a problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the log of the nimbus?
Generally, the nimbus will be in a running state until you stop it, or it faces an error. If you want to be sure about your nimbus status, you can check the log of your nimbus (./logs/nimbus.log).

Answer (score 0):

on running **./storm nimbus** command. The process has started as it is showing in your example. This is the usual behavior.

If you want to run the storm in the background, try to run it with the nohup command

**nohup ./storm nimbus > storms.log &**